# Verification Check returning NULL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am unsure why I am still getting an answer of `NULL` even if it does exist in the DB.  I am also getting it for a value that is not in the DB and it should be inserted.

**Model:**

```
function pageURLCheck($title, $id)
{
    $this->db->select('post_title, website_id');
    $this->db->where('post_title', $title);
    $this->db->where('website_id', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get($this->_table['posts']);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$urlCheck = $this->page_model->pageURLCheck($post['post_title'],  $website_id);

if($urlCheck == NULL)
{
  $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Page Title Exists', 'error'); 
}else{
 $save_success = $this->page_model->save($post, $action, $post_id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model function is **not returning** anything, so when you call it from the controller (`$urlCheck = $this->page_model->pageURLCheck($post['post_title'],  $website_id);`) you get `NULL`.

Just add a `return` to the method:

```
function pageURLCheck($title, $id)
{
    $this->db->select('post_title, website_id');
    $this->db->where('post_title', $title);
    $this->db->where('website_id', $id);

    return $this->db->get($this->_table['posts']);
}
```

Also, *don't check for NULL* In the controller, since you are not retrieving values (i.e. no `result_array()` or `results()`), so you always get an **object** back (of DB class).

**UPDATE**

re-reading your question, looks like you want to check if something exists and that's all, so you should do something like this:

```
function pageURLCheck($title, $id)
{
    $this->db->select('post_title, website_id');
    $this->db->where('post_title', $title);
    $this->db->where('website_id', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get($this->_table['posts']);
    return $query->num_rows();  // <-- return the number of rows found in resultset
}
```

**controller**:

```
$urlCheck = $this->page_model->pageURLCheck($post['post_title'],  $website_id);

if($urlCheck > 0){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Page Title Exists', 'error'); 
} 
else{
    $save_success = $this->page_model->save($post, $action, $post_id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have just tried this but its adding duplicate 'post_title' now

Comment: That's a query fault maybe, try running it from the console or phpmyadmin to see if the results are the same. Anyway, the `return` is mandatory here

Comment: Just check if you get results (i.e. if num_rows > 0 --> you already have a title, else you don't)